# how to create a view/table from a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVeos.png)

so i have the following table and want to create a query that will output the days it was most requested.
for example on 01/02/2000 there was 3 requests in total, on 02/02/2000 there was 2 request in total, on 03/03/2000 there was 6 request in total and on 04/02/2000 there was 4 request in total. so basically i want to output this in table is that possible or will it be easier to just create another table with all this info and make dates a foreign key?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output as text, Also what datatype is your date and why do you imagine creating another table would be useful I wonder..

Comment: What is your actual issue? You may test by yourself and decide if it is possible or not. If you'll face some issues, then ask about **that specific issues**. Separate tables of aggregated data or denormalized tables are always a subject for syncronization issues

Comment: select DAYOFWEEK, MAX(Count(DAYOFWEEK)) as Total from customers Group by DAYOFWEEK ORDER BY MAX(COUNT(DAYODWEEK)); i have tried this, so managed to get them all outputed in the table but the expected output i want is the highest number of request in the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the date with highest number of request you can use `rownum` like below:

```
select * from 
(select Date,Count(Date) as Total from Table Group by Date
order by Count(Date) desc)
where rownum=1;
```

or you can use `row_number()` window function as below:

```
with cte as
(
   select Date,Count(Date) as Total ,row_number()over( order by Count(Date) desc)rn from employees
   group by Date
)
select Date, Total from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

use group by count like this

```
select Date,Count(Date) as Total from Table Group by Date
```

Comment: thankyou that did that count for me, any idea how i can get the highest number of requests made in a day outputted. for example only show the row for 03/nov/2000 - 6 in total request